# Android Navigation toolbar remove end space

Tags: android, navigation, android-toolbar, android-appbarlayout

I want to remove the end space of the navigation bar. I want the WhatsApp icon clip to the end. I also tried `app:contentInsetEnd="0dp"` and `app:contentInsetRight="0dp"`. I couldn't find the answer to removing end space. please help me to solve this UI design issue. also, I tried a negative margin but the issue remains.

[image: Home Page Image]

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".activity.dashboard.ActivityDashboard">

    <com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

        <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@color/white"
            app:contentInsetLeft="0dp"
            app:contentInsetStart="0dp"
            app:contentInsetStartWithNavigation="0dp"
            app:contentInsetEnd="0dp"
            app:contentInsetRight="0dp"
            app:contentInsetEndWithActions="0dp"
            app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay">

            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/toolbar_title"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:fontFamily="@font/colabbol"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:text="Home Screen"
                    android:textColor="@color/colorBlack"
                    android:textSize="@dimen/_20sdp" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textview_ramumunimji"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
                    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                    android:fontFamily="@font/colabreg"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:text="@string/RAMU_MUNIMJI"
                    android:textColor="@color/black"
                    android:textSize="@dimen/_13sdp"
                    android:visibility="gone" />

                <ImageView
                    android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/_5sdp"
                    android:id="@+id/imageviewRamumunimji"
                    android:visibility="gone"
                    android:layout_width="@dimen/_20sdp"
                    android:layout_height="@dimen/_20sdp"
                    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
                    android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                    android:src="@drawable/ic_whatsapp_1" />
                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/imageviewWhatsaapshare"
                    android:visibility="visible"
                    android:layout_width="@dimen/_20sdp"
                    android:layout_height="@dimen/_20sdp"
                    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
                    android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                    android:src="@drawable/ic_whatsapp_1" />

            </RelativeLayout>


        </androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar>

    </com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>

    <include layout="@layout/content_activity_dashboard" />

    <com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fab"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
        android:visibility="gone"
        app:srcCompat="@android:drawable/ic_dialog_email" />
    <!--android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"-->

</androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Comment: Are you inflating a menu in the toolbar? (eg. onCreateOptionsMenu ?)

Comment: Yes. But on the left side. there is a navigation drawer.

Comment: It should work.Check if there is the overflow menu with a white icon.

Comment: it works. thanks, @GabrieleMariotti. I overflowed the menu. after removing it works perfectly.